# Issue with animating Matplotlib-Seaborn subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation, subplot

My current goal is to animate two sets of data simultaneous on a single plot with 2 subplots. I previously asked a question here about clearing the axes data with [animated seaborn graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182644/animating-matplotlib-seaborn-plots-through-pandas), but rather than clearing the data on the axes, I need to append/update them (i.e.: [something like the animated plots here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-animated-graphs-in-python-bb619cc2dec1)). To make matters more complicated, one of my sets of data are stored in numpy arrays whereas the other set is stored in a pandas dataframe.

I tried using some test data before using my actual data, but that doesn't work, especially when I try to animate the data stored in the dataframe:

```
import math, os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import animation

def update(i,pass_data,fig,axes,sort_yrs,ani,x_val,y_val):
    fil_pass_data = pass_data[pass_data['year'] == sort_yrs[i]]
    fig.suptitle(r"Year = {}".format(sorted_yrs[i]),fontsize = 35,y = 1.000)
    axes[1] = sns.lineplot(x = 'year',y = 'passengers',data = fil_pass_data,hue = 'month',
                           hue_order = sort_yrs,palette = 'Set1',legend = False)
    ani1.set_data(x_val[:i],y_val[:i])

#Read/Generate Data  
passenger_df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
yrs_of_int = ['Jan','Mar','Jun','Jul','Dec']
fil_pass_df = passenger_df[passenger_df['month'].isin(yrs_of_int)]
sorted_yrs = sorted(fil_pass_df['year'].unique())
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,fil_pass_df['year'].unique().shape[0])
y = np.sin(x)

#Initialize figure and plot initial points
fig,axes = plt.subplots(ncols = 2,figsize = (15,7))
axes[0].plot(x[0],y[0],color = 'tab:red',label = 'Initial Point',marker = 'o',markersize = 5)
sns.lineplot(x = 'year',y = 'passengers',
             data = fil_pass_df[fil_pass_df['year'] == sorted_yrs[0]],
             hue = 'month',hue_order = yrs_of_int,palette = 'Set1')
ani1, = axes[0].plot(x[0],y[0],color = 'tab:blue',label = 'Dynamic Response')

#Formatting
axes[0].legend(loc='lower right')
axes[0].set_ylim(-1.1*np.pi,1.1*np.pi)
axes[0].set_xlim(-0.1,1.1*2*np.pi)
axes[1].set_xlim(fil_pass_df['year'].min()-1,fil_pass_df['year'].min()+1)
axes[1].set_ylim(100,700)
             
axes[0].set_title('Test Plot',fontsize = 15,pad = 5)  
axes[1].set_title('Passengers by Month',fontsize = 15,pad = 5)
axes[0].set_ylabel(r"$\sin(x)$",fontsize = 20,labelpad = 10)
axes[0].set_xlabel(r"$x$",fontsize = 20,labelpad = 10)
axes[1].set_ylabel("Passenger Count",fontsize = 20,labelpad = 10)
axes[1].set_xlabel("Year",fontsize = 20,labelpad = 10)

#Create animation and save it
animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs = 
(fil_pass_df,fig,axes,sorted_yrs,ani1,x,y),
                                      frames=range(0,len(sorted_yrs)),interval=0.5, 
blit=False,repeat=True)
animation.save('test.mp4',
                fps = 1, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'],dpi = 200)
```

The test mp4 file that is generated from here animates the left most plot (numpy array data), but fails to plot the right most plot (seaborn data). I have four theories as to why it doesn't work:

1. I'm not supposed to initialize the right most figure parameters before the `update` call. Instead, the figure parameters need to be set in `update`.
2. The fact that I'm specifying `hue` in the `update` function is somehow messing up with matplotlib's animation.
3. The fact that my data is either in numpy arrays or a pandas dataframe.
4. I'm overthinking this and forgot to one command in my code that makes this work.

I tried moving the right figure formatting into `update` but that didn't seem to work, so it might be bullet points #2-4.

Does anyone know why this is happening/how to solve it? For subplot animations, is there a rule as to whether everything should be stored in the same data type?